# All item not appending while looping

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
def PatternMatching(Pattern, Genome):
    positions = [] # output variable    
    for i in range(len(Genome)-len(Pattern)+1):    
        if Genome[i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
            print(i, Pattern)
            positions.append(Genome.index(Pattern))    
    return positions
# Now, set Text equal to the oriC of Vibrio cholerae and Pattern equal to "TGATCA"
Pattern = "TGATCA"
Genome="ATCAATGATCAACGTAAGCTTCTAAGCATGATCAAGGTGCTCACACAGTTTATCCACAACCTGAGTGGATGACATCAAGATAGGTCGTTGTATCTCCTTCCTCTCGTACTCTCATGACCACGGAAAGATGATCAAGAGAGGATGATTTCTTGGCCATATCGCAATGAATACTTGTGACTTGTGCTTCCAATTGACATCTTCAGCGCCATATTGCGCTGGCCAAGGTGACGGAGCGGGATTACGAAAGCATGATCATGGCTGTTGTTCTGTTTATCTTGTTTTGACTGAGACTTGTTAGGATAGACGGTTTTTCATCACTGACTAGCCAAAGCCTTACTCTGCCTGACATCGACCGTAAATTGATAATGAATTTACATGCTTCCGCGACGATTTACCTCTTGATCATCGATCCGATTGAAGATCTTCAATTGTTAATTCTCTTGCCTCGACTCATAGCCATGATGAGCTCTTGATCATGTTTCCTTAACCCTCTATTTTTTACGGAAGAATGATCAAGCTGCTGCTCTTGATCATCGTTTC"    

print(PatternMatching(Pattern, Genome))
```

This function return only [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] but correct output will be [5,28,128,249,399,470,509,527]

Why first matching index returned for all subsequent matching?

Comment: `some_string.index(another_string)` returns position of first occurrence of `another_string` is `some_string`. You need to rethink what exactly is appended to `positions`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error in the code. Line positions.append(Genome.index(Pattern)) should be replaced with positions.append(i). That gives the correct result.